# Insert JSON in Array Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a `dict` created in a for loop in Python `dict = {year:{month:{day:[title]}}}` where `year`, `month`, `day`, and `title` are all variables. I then use `data = json.dumps(dict)` which works perfectly. But if the day is the same, I'd like it to add another `[title]` aspect to the array, so it would be

```
for title in x:
    dict = {year:{month:{day:[title]}}}
    data = json.dumps(dict)
if day==day:
    //insert another [title] right next to [title]
```

I've tried using `append`, `update`, and `insert`, but none of them work.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: That's not an array. That's a dict. Even in JSON terminology, it's an object, not an array.

Comment: Then check and add the `[title]` **before** you dump it? Also as @user2357112 said, you are not making a Python list (JSON array), you're making a dict. (JSON object).

Comment: @CaseyFalk That makes sense, but how do I add it?

Comment: And what does "Title right next to title" mean? :/

Comment: @user3822146, what do you mean "add"? What are you trying to get as a result?

Comment: I want the result to be `dict = {year:{month:{day:[title],[title]}}}` but please note that the second `[title]` should be different from the first

Comment: `day:[title],[title]` or `day:[title, anotherTitle]`? Note that the first is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that as [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112) mentioned, you are creating a Python `dict` -- not a Python `list` (aka a JSON "array"). Thus, when you say "[title] right next to [title]" there is a bit of confusion. Dicts do not use the order you are expecting (they use a hash-ordering).

That, and **you are attempting to add a field *after* you've dumped the JSON to a string**. You should do that *before* you dump it. More so, **you're throwing away both your `dict` and `data` variables every loop**. As written, your code will only have access to the variables in the last iteration of the loop.

And another important note: **don't overload `dict`**. Rename your variable to something else.

Also, your line **`day==day` will always return `True`**...

Here is what I *think* you are trying to do: you are creating a "calendar" of sorts that is organized into years, then months, then days. Each day has a list of "titles."

```
# Variables I'm assuming exist:
# `title`, `year`, `month`, `day`, `someOtherDay`, `titles`, `someOtherTitle`

myDict = {}
for title in titles: #Renamed `x` to `titles` for clarity.
    # Make sure myDict has the necessary keys.
    if not myDict[year]:
        myDict[year] = {}
    if not myDict[year][month]: 
        myDict[year][month] = {}

    # Set the day to be a list with a single `title` (and possibly two).
    myDict[year][month][day] = [title]
    if day==someOtherDay:
        myDict[year][month][day].append(someotherTitle)

    # And FINALLY dump the result to a string.
    data = json.dumps(myDict)
```